# How do I diagnose CPU trashing in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage

I'm running 64 bit Windows 10.0.14393 on a Dell XPS 13 (8GB RAM, quad i7-5600U 2.6GHz). Recently I have noticed that the fan is constantly on and the CPU is running between 60% and 100%. The task manager reports that "Service Host" is perminantly taking most of the CPU:

[image: Task Manager screenshot showing Service Host]

I have tried a number of things to remedy this CPU usage:

- Leaving the laptop running for a few days
- Turning off bitlocker
- Turning off Cortana
  ([here](http://www.howtogeek.com/265027/how-to-disable-cortana-in-windows-10/))
- RegEdit for time broker ([here](http://news.softpedia.com/news/windows-10-high-cpu-usage-fix-490908.shtml))

These did not work and they feel worryingly random.

What tools and techniques should I use to diagnose which hosted service within Service Host is causing the prolonged high CPU utilization?

Comment: I would suspect that one of your "services" is hung up in a loop.  Windows Update is famous for doing this on Vista and 7, and would seem to be a likely candidate here.  You should be able to somehow stop the Windows Update service (on Vista it's Control Panel/Admin Tools/Services/Windows Update/Stop) and see if that makes the symptoms go away.  (How to then "fix" Windows Update is a different question.)

Comment: Is there a more systematic way to work out which service is the offender?

Comment: I've not found one on Vista.  But on Vista, at least, stopping WU is fairly simple and unlikely to cause problems -- you can restart it after 5 minutes if it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Less simple for me as that feature's locked by my IT department

Comment: Just to be sure: have you tried restarting computer? (shutdown is different process when fast boot is enabled)

Comment: LOL. I have restarted. Can you explain how that helps diagnose the problem? I'm a little worried that the answers are trying to fix the problem, while my question is about how to diagnose it.

Comment: Had to ask :) Everyone is just used to simply restarting/killing service to "fix" bug on Microsoft side ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is difficult to diagnose this sort of problem without being able to test "solutions".  M$ OS diagnostics are pretty sucky.

Comment: have you tried ProcessExplorer/Hacker? do you see which service caused it.

Comment: @DanielRHicks your comment is useless as hell. both tools are available as ZIP to run portable, so no need to install anything.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - They will require supervisor authority to run.

Comment: @DanielRHicks no, both can be run as normal users, but show less data. To see which service is causing it, he must run them as admin, this is true.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ProcessExplorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) or [ProcessHacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) show the properties of the `svchost` process. Start both tools as admin, go to the `Threads` tab and here both tools show a column which to which service the calls belong.

[image]

In this picture some CPU usage comes from the IP Helper service.

In the [Windows 10 Creators Update since Build 14942](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/10/07/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14942-for-pc/) Microsoft isolates each service again if you use a PC with more than 3.5GB RAM so that you can easily see which service belongs to which `svchost` process:

> If your PC has 3.5+ GB of memory, you may notice an increased number
>   of processes in Task Manager. While this change may look concerning at
>   first glance, many will be excited to find out the motivation behind
>   this change. As the number of preinstalled services grew, they began
>   to get grouped into processes known as service hosts (svchost.exe’s)
>   with Windows 2000. Note that the recommended RAM for PC’s for this
>   release was 256 MB, while the minimum RAM was 64MB. Because of the
>   dramatic increase in available memory over the years, the
>   memory-saving advantage of service hosts has diminished.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

It's a hardware issue.

You either have clogged heatsink's radiators or motherboard is faulty - i.e. temp controller module gone bad.

Thus the reason CPU is constantly on full load is due to it being throttled down to not overheat it.

If machine is under warranty report it to Dell.

EDIT: Usually (> 90%) this was the cause of such issue when servicing Dell laptops as a Dell Certified Engineer.

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: @dumbledad Task Manager -> Perforance tab -> CPU -> Top right corner.  It is displayed as [Processor name] @ [current clock speed]. [Intel Ark](https://ark.intel.com/products/85215/Intel-Core-i7-5600U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz) states your CPU speed at 2.6Ghz (3.2 GHz with turbo), if it goes below those values when in High Performance power plan and plugged (Power plans may lower speed) then it would be throttled down.

Comment: That's useful - it reads 3.06 GHz. That doesn't seem badly throttled.

Comment: @dumbledad - As PTwr says. However, be aware you may see constant change of that depending on power settings - my i7-4510U on idle shows ~1GHz (from 0.8 to 1.1), on load it's spiking to 2.3GHz

Comment: @dumbledad - have a look here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx. Tested on W10, working